# apt-get upgrade not working after upgrade from stable to testing: error cycle with libc-bin package

Tags: linux, debian, upgrade, apt-get, apt

I upgraded from debian stable to debian testing, and now I am not able to do `apt-get upgrade` anymore.

When I do that I get this error:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-6) ...
dpkg: cycle found while processing triggers:
 chain of packages whose triggers are or may be responsible:
  libc-bin -> man-db
 packages' pending triggers which are or may be unresolvable:
  man-db: /usr/share/man
  libc-bin: ldconfig
dpkg: error processing package man-db (--configure):
 triggers looping, abandoned
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-6) ...
dpkg: cycle found while processing triggers:
 chain of packages whose triggers are or may be responsible:
  libc-bin -> libc-bin -> libc-bin
 packages' pending triggers which are or may be unresolvable:
  libc-bin: ldconfig
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 triggers looping, abandoned
Errors were encountered while processing:
 man-db
 libc-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What I tried is:

- `apt-get upgrade -f`
- `apt-get --reinstall install libc-bin`

Comment: Why not do a fresh install, instead of trying to "upgrade" stable to testing?

Comment: cause I needed to do that. And debian should be strong cause of that. you can pass from stable to testing to untesting without so much effort.

Comment: All the sources are ok, à la https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting ? What does dist-upgrade want to do?

Comment: The sources are ok, I checked more than once. I did not understand your second question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Error on `Debian 8`, and solved for me so:

```
dpkg --configure --no-triggers libc-bin
apt-get install -f
```

And, Then `install` or `upgrade` my packages.

I hope, be useful.